# Java Spring Integration Mail - IllegalArgumentException: 'taskScheduler' must not be null

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, jakarta-mail, imap

I have some problems converting Imap Idle XML configuration (which works well) to Java Config (which does not work).

I'm pretty new with Spring, so the problem is probably trivial. 
Thanks for your help!

XML Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd"
       xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
       xmlns:int-mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util">

    <int:channel id="emails"/>

    <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
        <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
        <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
        <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
        <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
    </util:properties>

    <int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter id="mailAdapter"
                                  store-uri="imaps://login:pass@imap-server:993/INBOX"
                                  java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties"
                                  channel="emails"
                                  should-delete-messages="false"
                                  should-mark-messages-as-read="true">
    </int-mail:imap-idle-channel-adapter>
</beans>
```

Java Config:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter;
import org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapMailReceiver;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageChannel;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
public class ImapConfig{

    private Properties javaMailProperties() {
        Properties javaMailProperties = new Properties();

        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback","false");
        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.store.protocol","imaps");
        javaMailProperties.setProperty("mail.debug","true");

        return javaMailProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageChannel messageChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    ImapIdleChannelAdapter mailAdapter() {
        ImapMailReceiver mailReceiver = new ImapMailReceiver("imaps://login:pass@imap-server:993/INBOX");
        mailReceiver.setJavaMailProperties(javaMailProperties());
        mailReceiver.setShouldDeleteMessages(false);
        mailReceiver.setShouldMarkMessagesAsRead(true);

        ImapIdleChannelAdapter imapIdleChannelAdapter = new ImapIdleChannelAdapter(mailReceiver);
        imapIdleChannelAdapter.setOutputChannel(messageChannel());

        return imapIdleChannelAdapter;
    }

}
```

Main.java:

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        ApplicationContext ac = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ImapConfig.class);
        DirectChannel inputChannel = ac.getBean("messageChannel", DirectChannel.class);
        inputChannel.subscribe(new MessageHandler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message<?> message) throws MessagingException {

                System.out.println(message);

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Exceptions:

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'mailAdapter'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'taskScheduler' must not be null
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'mailAdapter'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'taskScheduler' must not be null
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:874)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'taskScheduler' must not be null
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.mail.ImapIdleChannelAdapter.doStart(ImapIdleChannelAdapter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173)
    ... 13 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: You should set `taskScheduler` in your code: `imapIdleChannelAdapter.setTaskScheduler(yourTaskScheduler);`

Answer (score 1):

You have missed `@EnableIntegration` on your `@Configuration`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.1.RELEASE/reference/html/overview.html#configuration-enable-integration

Comment: You should also make the `ImapMailReceiver` a `@Bean` as well - so that Spring manages it properly.

Comment: You can also [get rid of the socket factory properties, they're not needed](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).